# Set Input Value to Javascript Variable Error

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, I want to copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip to the Billing Name and Billing Zip if the check box is selected.

When I execute the following code, it shows [object HTMLInputElement] in both Billing Name and Billing Zip fields.

```
function billingFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
        var name = document.getElementById('shippingName');
        var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip');
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = name;
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = zip;
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = ""
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = ""
    }

}
```

Comment: add a '.value' after the lines that assign name and zip too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add value after variables like below code:

```
function billingFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
        var name = document.getElementById('shippingName');
        var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip');
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = name.value;
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = zip.value;
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = ""
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning the objects your variables but not the value

```js
function billingFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById('same').checked){
        var name = document.getElementById('shippingName');
        var zip = document.getElementById('shippingZip');
         name=name.value;
         zip=zip.value;
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = name;
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = zip;
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = ""
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = ""
    }

}
```